# How can create Bundle id on member center for Custom keyboard

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

How can create Bundle id for Custom keyboard

Comment: You can create by using a normal procedure,But you need to have a two bundle id,one for container app and other for custom keyboard extension.

Comment: yes, problem is there. 

when i create new app id on member center at that time ask me one bundle identifire.
so where second bundle id register

because  how can register keyboard extenstion bundle id